# What does Rey mean by this statement?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Rey says to Kylo Ren, after healing him:

> Rey: I did want to take your hand, Ben's Hand.

What does Rey mean by this statement?

Comment: It's a call-back to an earlier scene; *“No, I have other plans,” he said. “I offered you my hand once. You wanted to take it. Why didn’t you?”*

Comment: "Take my hand? Like that really cool guy Darth Vader did to my uncle?!?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She no longer sees him as [Kylo Ren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylo_Ren) - the Leader of the [First Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Order_(Star_Wars)), enemy of the rebel alliance and the remains of the Jedi, she sees him as she wishes he was - Ben Solo, the son of Han and Leia, a friend and ally.

This indicates another waypoint in the profound shift in the relationship between the characters from enemies to allies, perhaps friends, maybe more. Certainly there was on Rey's part a desire to trust, a willingness to heal the breach between them.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a call back to TLJ when he held out his gloved hand to her asking her to join him. Rian Johnson has said it’s supposed to be a romantic proposal not a business partnership. It’s loosely based in the proposal scene from Pride and Prejudice when D’Arcy first proposes to Elizabeth. His holding out his gloved hand represents Kylo Ren extending his hand to her, which is why she refuses him. His unloved hand represents Ben Solo. A more kind and gentle man.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a better answer if you could cite the exact quote from Johnson.